# How to check if p12 certificate match hostname in java?

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, tls1.2

In our application we let users to create custom connections to LDAP. They can upload certificates and type parameters for LDAP connections.

I would like to test if this URL will match with uploaded certificate.
I'm aware that such test happen during connection, but I want to notify users before that.

I'm aware of HostnameVerifier interface (and default implementation), however I don't have a good idea how construct SSLContext. I can perform test connection, however a new certificate will be not included in keystore and such connection will fail.

Maybe such test might be static and there is a tool that can compare CN and/or SAN names with hostname?

Comment: It is not clear for me that you would like to test the certificate before you put it into production or you would like to validate the cert of the connection? If we are talking about the first case, please provide the format/extension of your certfile.

Comment: Another question is that you have to validate it using java? You have other [options](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/openssl-command-cheatsheet-b441be1e8c4a) that does not require java.

Comment: @m4gic We have to validate it using Java, users have a possibility to upload a certificate and type credentials and URL. Main reason for such check is to forbid saving any certificate that will not be useful during connection. After consideration we decided to test connection with Start TLS.